# Multiple PathParam for jax-rs

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Im using Jersey for jax-rs and I have two methods in my Resource

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/Updates")
public FileBrowserLoadResult getUpdates() {
    return getUpdates("", "");
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/Updates"+"/{id: [0-9]+}{path: .*}")
public FileBrowserLoadResult getUpdates(@PathParam("id")String id, @PathParam("path") String path) {
    return null;
}
```

Is it possible to combine the path so I don't have to implement two methods? The Parameter can be empty but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Did you try to use "/Updates/{id:[0-9]*}{path:.*}" in @Path? This should make the id optional.

Comment: thank you how can i call the method only with /Updates wihtouth the end slash ? just /Updates not /Updates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
@Path("/Updates{id : (/[0-9]+)?}{path : .*}")
```

But I haven't tested